# Shift operation grouping by a certain column SQL

Tags: sql, select, greenplum

So I'm with **GreenPlum** on a big table name **purchases** containing more than 4 million of rows. Here is an example of this table:

```
userId |        purchaseTime      | timeDiff
------------------------------------------
 17    |   2016-02-01 11:01:02    |
 17    |   2016-02-01 13:24:58    |
 17    |   2016-02-01 21:12:36    |
 67    |   2016-02-01 17:04:49    |
 84    |   2016-02-01 16:13:20    |
 94    |   2016-02-01 05:46:13    |
 94    |   2016-02-01 21:33:19    |
```

---

**The table was ordered by userID and purchaseTime to help understand my goal**

My objective is to update this table by including the difference of time between the current row and the last purchased time for each user.

Making it look like this:

```
userId |        purchaseTime      | timeDiff
------------------------------------------
 17    |   2016-02-01 11:01:02    | NULL
 17    |   2016-02-01 13:24:58    | 2:23:56
 17    |   2016-02-01 21:12:36    | 8:12:38
 67    |   2016-02-01 17:04:49    | NULL
 84    |   2016-02-01 16:13:20    | NULL
 94    |   2016-02-01 05:46:13    | NULL
 94    |   2016-02-01 21:33:19    | 16:13:06
```

**The select from one of your answer helped me**. Now I need to do the UPDATE but I'm getting a syntax error near the UPDATE doing:

```
WITH tmp_table AS
(
    SELECT userId ,  
       purchaseTime ,
       purchaseTime - LAG(purchaseTime )
       OVER (PARTITION BY userId  ORDER BY purchaseTime) AS timeDiff
    FROM   purchases
)

UPDATE purchases SET timeDiff = tmp_table.timeDiff
FROM tmp_table
WHERE userId   = tmp_table.userId  
AND purchaseTime = tmp_table.purchaseTime;
```

Can any one help me update my table?

Comment: Use the Lag function to get the desired result.

Comment: If you are updating the entire table, it would much better to create a new table.  You will basically double the size on disk if you update the entire table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basing myself on the query from @mureinik, in order to do the update you have to do the following :

```
UPDATE purchases
SET timeDiff = tmp_table.timeDiff
FROM (SELECT userId, purchaseTime ,
       (EXTRACT(epoch FROM purchaseTime - LAG(purchaseTime) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY purchaseTime))/60)::integer AS timeDiff
        FROM   purchases) AS tmp_table
WHERE purchases.userId = tmp_table.userId
AND purchases.timeDiff = tmp_table.timeDiff;
```

In the update you will have the `EXTRACT` and `epoch FROM` statements, that's in order to return the number of seconds in the interval. If you want them in minutes divide it by 60 `\60` and finally if you want to round it, just cast it to `integer`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lag` window function to find the previous purchase date, and just subtract the two:

```
SELECT userId,  
       purchaseTime,
       purchaseTime - 
        LAG(purchaseTime) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY purchaseTime) AS timeDiff
FROM   purchases
```

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik this made what I was looking for, but I'm a basic user of GreenPlum, could you guide me on how to update my table?